# Is there a way to play Portal 2's Perpetual Testing Initiative in splitscreen mode?

Tags: portal-2

I know that some of the community maps made for Portal 2 allow for two players. The last I checked though, I could not find a way to play those maps in splitscreen mode the way you can play the Atlas/P-Body campaign. Does anyone know if I've missed something there?

Comment: How did you get splitscreen mode to work? I can only find hacky ways. And one of the guides - http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?l=polish&id=239373369 - links to another guide for workshop coop maps: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=32892213&postcount=644

Comment: Valve should have added official support, at least for the main robot missions. It might just involve pressing start on a second controller during the lobby system. I just couldn't get the workshop levels.